# How to calculate "expected" number of inversions in a semi-random array of integers?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, math, random

Consider an array a of integers. A pair (i,j) is called an inversion in A if i < j and A[i] > A[j].

For every position 'i' in the array there are two possible candidates: a[i] with probability p[i] and a[i]+x with probability 1-p[i].

Now I have to calculate expected number of inversions.
Given a[i] and p[i] for every index i and an integer x.

I know the O(n^2) approach (check every legal possible pair).
Also, I know the O(nlogn) approach to calculate the number of inversions in an array in which all the elements are predetermined with 100% probability. It is done by modifying merge sort.

I want to know an approach better than n squared. Please let me know.

Comment: Why do you expect there to be a better solution than O(*n* log(*n* ))?

Comment: I know nlogn solution only when all the elements of the array are known already with 100% probability, but not in this case where there are two candidates for every position.

Comment: Oh, for this problem, are you sure there is a O(n**2) solution?  I think there are 2**length(a) different combinations.  If you have such an approach, can you explain what it is?

Comment: There are C(n,2) = O(n^2) total possible pairs. Of these I have to check only those pairs (i,j) where i < j. Checking each pair takes O(1) time.

Comment: I don't have to create every possible instance of the array. For any pair (i,j) I have to determine the probability of inversion. Knowing ai, pi and x I can do this in O(1) time.

Comment: Are you supposed to write a program to do this? This is pretty much just a probability problem (actually, I did it for homework once in an Algorithms class) that has a nice "on paper" solution.

And off the top of my head, I think the expected number was lg(n).

Comment: No it can not always be lg(n). Answer depends on input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done with a simple modification to the standard merge-sort based algorithm for counting inversions, where we assign a weight to each value and compute the sum of `W[i]*W[j]` for `i<j`, `A[i]>A[j]` (when each weight is 1, we get the normal count). Instead of adding to the count the number of elements remaining in the left array, we add the sum of the weights for these elements multiplied by the weight of the element in the right array we are processing.

To use this algorithm to solve the posed problem, simply create an array of twice the size, where each element in the original array is replaced by two elements (in sorted order), with weights given by the probabilities.

Comment: On what basis should I assign weights? How can I even sort the array whose elements are not predetermined with 100% probability. Can you please elaborate your point further??

Comment: @AbhinavChauhan: Re-read the last paragraph -- you create a different array to run the weighted inversion count algorithm on.

Comment: Please tell me one more thing.....We create another array B and for every position 'i' in A we put two elements ai and (ai+x) in B and assign them weights pi and (1-pi) respectively....Now we have an array B. The probability that an element ei is present in B is equal to the weight of ei. But e1 (=a[1]) and e2 (=a[1]+x) can't occur simultaneously in A. Thus the two events corresponding to the occurrence of e1 and e2 are not independent. But the solution ( which is correct ) suggested by you assumes that events of occurence of all the elements are independent of each other. How come??

Comment: @AbhinavChauhan: If I understand your concern correctly, this should be fine because of the linearity of expectation (E(X+Y) = E(X)+E(Y)).

Answer (score 0):

I left a comment explaining this, but you can have an O(1) calculation of this if you just use a little bit of math. I'll spare you the work, but, by my calculations, the expected number of inversions in an array of n integers is ((n^2) - (n)) / 4. Sorry for the abundance of parentheses, I just wanted to make sure that was totally clear. I can post the work if you want it, but I figured I'd leave it out if you just need the answer.

So, despite what my comment says, I remembered incorrectly. It's not lg(n).

Comment: The answer depends on `x` and the values `a1 .. an` and `p1 .. pn`, it can't always be `((n^2) - (n)) / 4`. For example, in the case where `a[i] == i` and `p[i] == 1` for all `i`, the expected number of inversions is 0 because the array is sorted with probability 1. I assume the question you're answering is something like "what is the expected number of inversions in a shuffled array", but this array isn't shuffled.

Comment: Oh, I seem to have misunderstood the question. I took it as though the array was randomly generated. My apologies for my misleading answer.